# Typo3 8.7.16 CKEditor: CKEditor includes css file from wrong extension

Tags: ckeditor, typo3, typoscript, ckeditor4.x, typo3-8.x

I've got a problem with CKEditor and an extension.

I have multiple extensions with the same functions, but with different configurations. For a new webproject the `demotemplate_extension` will be copied for example to `newsite1template_extension`. The extensions have also configurations for CKEditor.

But the problem is, when I edit a content element in Project B,C,D..., the `rte.css` always included from Project A. I checked the paths in the config (`contentCSS=`), which are looking right (i.e. `.../ext/template_projectB` [not `projectA`]). Any ideas? (caches cleared,...)

[image: ckeditor]

Comment: Okay. Now I'm one step further. The ckeditor uses the config from the last loaded extension!

Answer (score 3):

As you already discovered yourself, the CKEditor will only use one configuration at a time.

But there's an easy solution: if you have a TYPO3 instance with multiple websites and different configuration, just use `registerPageTSConfigFile`. You'll be able to assign configuration on a pagetree basis in the page properties (Tab "Resources", *Include Page TSConfig (from extensions)*.

Add the following code to your template extension:

`your_extension/Configuration/TCA/Overrides/pages.php`

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::registerPageTSConfigFile(
    'your_extension',
    'Configuration/TSconfig/Page/rte_ckeditor.tsconfig',
    'Template Extension: Config for NEW Rich Text Editor (CKEditor)'
);
```

In the file `rte_ckeditor.tsconfig` you need this line:

```
RTE.default.preset = your_rte_preset
```

Also, you need to add the following line to your `ext_localconf.php`:

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['RTE']['Presets']['your_rte_preset'] = 'EXT:your_extension/Configuration/RTE/Custom.yaml';
```

For each website you can assign a new CKEditor preset and PageTSconfig file like this.